# How to fade in text as each line is entered?

Tags: css, meteor

I have a collection called 'log'. Logs gets populated repeatedly throughout the life of the application, such as:

```
12:15 - User xyz doing something
12:13 - Server doing something
12:12 - Server starts
```

... etc

It's a simple publish/subscribe mechanism, nothing added. The template just loops through each elements of the collection and formats it as needed. Each line is in a div for easy styling.

I'd like to add a fadein effect. I tried adding a fadein to the div (from boostrap) and it applies to all elements everytime the collection changes, that is, it appears that Meteor re-renders the entire template rather than 'adding' a new element to the list of divs.

Is there a way to do this in meteor?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but the solution is as follow. I hope it helps someone:

In handlebars:

```
<div id="{{_id}}" class="logItem fade-class">
  <span>{{logItem}}</span>
</div>
```

In Template.js:

```
Template.myTemplate.preserve({
  '.item[id]': function (node) { return node.id; }
});
```

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor re-renders the template, but DOM elements are preserved. You just need to mark them so that you won't trigger the fade again:

```
Template.list.rendered = function() {
    _.each(this.findAll('.item'), function(element) {
        if($(element).data('faded')) return;
        $(element).data('faded', true);

        $(element).fadeIn(); // Or whatever you like here
    });
};
```

Comment: Sadly, no dice. .item elements are looped through by handledbars and re-rendered. I tried preserving their state by using preserve in Meteor on their selector, and that only preserves the state of the newly added lines. The old ones are still re-rendered, wiping any key/value pair found in .data()